# Multiprocess sqlite INSERT: "database is locked"

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocess

*(Please note: There is a question called "**SQLite3 and Multiprocessing**" but that question is actually about **multithreading** and so is the accepted answer, this isn't a duplicate)*

I'm implementing a multiprocess script, each process will need to write some results in an sqlite table. My program keeps crashing with `database is locked` (with sqlite only one DB modification is allowed at a time).

Here's an example of what I have:

```
def scan(n):
    n = n + 1 # Some calculation

    cur.execute("                      \
                    INSERT INTO hello  \
                    (n)                \
                    VALUES ('"+n+"')   \
                ")

    con.commit()
    con.close()

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(processes=int(sys.argv[1]))

    for status in pool.imap_unordered(scan, range(0,9999)):
        if status:
            print "ok"

    pool.close()
```

I've tried using a lock by declaring a lock in the main and using it as a global in `scan()`, but it didn't stop me getting the `database is locked`.

**What is the proper way of making sure only one INSERT statement will get issued at the same time in a multiprocess Python script?**

EDIT:

I'm running on a Debian-based Linux.

Comment: What's your operating system? SQLite supports advisory / region locking for competition between competing writers, so even though one write can happen at a time, on an appropriate operating system with appropriate configuration, this just results it being slow / blocking for other writers to be done, not on this.

Comment: This is discussed in detail in http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html. For that matter -- specifically, which version of SQLite is this? If it's pre-3.0 (which it shouldn't be -- that's over a decade old), then you don't have that feature.

Comment: On a completely different note, by the way -- don't EVER use string concatenation to build your SQL queries. That way lies Bobby Tables...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm on a Debian based system. I would never use that on anything with foreign input! Is it really ill-advised even for small temporary script? I will take a look at your link.

Comment: Even if it's not security-impacting, it's performance-impacting -- means a cached query parse can't be (re)used.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What's the backend filesystem? If you're on vfat, I could see region locking not working properly.

Comment: BTW, I asked about the sqlite version; since you're using the Python library, you can `print sqlite3.sqlite_version` to get that.

Comment: sqlite 3.7.16.2 and I must admit I do not know how to check my backend filesystem

Comment: Reading the fine manual for the Python module, I'm thinking it's likely that the filesystem isn't involved in the issue -- see the provided answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will happen if the write lock can't be grabbed within (by default) a 5-second timeout. In general, make sure your code COMMITs its transactions with sufficient frequency, thereby releasing the lock and letting other processes have a chance to grab it. If you want to wait for longer, you can do that:

```
db = sqlite.connect(filename, timeout=30.0)
```

...waits for 30 seconds.

Comment: Excellent! If I have multiple INSERTs should I release the lock between each? Or issue each in a row and then commit?

Comment: Ideally, for performance, you want to find a reasonable middle ground in terms of batch size. Too short and you take more time overall, too big and your individual transactions take too long (and hold the lock for an extended period). Of course, sometimes correctness concerns will dictate batch size more strongly than performance does.